# check if the string begin with euro/pound symbol

Tags: php, string, special-characters

I'm trying to check if a string is start with '€' or '£' in PHP.

Below are the codes

```
    $text = "€123";

    if($text[0] == "€"){
        echo "true";
    }
    else{
        echo "false";
    }

    //output false
```

If only check a single char, it works fine

```
    $symbol = "€";

    if($symbol == "€"){
        echo "true";
    }
    else{
        echo "false";
    }
    // output true
```

I have also tried to print the string on browser.

```
$text = "€123";
echo $text; //display euro symbol correctly
echo $text[0] //get a question mark
```

I have tried to use `substr()`, but the same problem occurred.

Comment: It displays as the question mark due to the encoding of the the multi-byte character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Characters, such as '€' or '£' are multi-byte characters.  There is an excellent article that you can [read here](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html).  According to the [PHP docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.substr), PHP strings are byte arrays. As a result, accessing or modifying a string using array brackets is not multi-byte safe, and should only be done with strings that are in a single-byte encoding such as ISO-8859-1.

Also make sure your file is encoded with UTF-8: you can use a text editor such as NotePad++ to convert it.

If I reduce the PHP to this, it works, the key being to use mb_substr:

```
<?php
  header ('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
  $text = "€123";
  echo mb_substr($text,0,1,'UTF-8');
?>
```

Finally, it would be a good idea to add the UTF-8 meta-tag in your head tag:

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

Comment: Sweet, I had the same problem with some registers that were imported with a euro or a pound sign and therefore everytime I had to display it to the screen, I had double signs all over and ``mb_substr`` saved me to cut the part of the string that I needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I suggest this as the easiest solution to you. Convert the symbols to their unicode identifiers using `htmlentities()`.

```
htmlentities($text, ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");
```

Which will either give you `&pound;` or `&euro;`. Now that allows you to run a `switch() {case:}` statement to check. (Or your if statements)

```
$symbols = explode(";", $text);

switch($symbols[0]) {
    case "&pound":
        echo "It's Pounds";
        break;
    case "&euro":
        echo "It's Euros";
        break;
}
```

[**`Working Example`**](http://www.tehplayground.com/#ZXSand1fe)

Answer (score 1):

This happens because you’re using a multi-byte character encoding (probably UTF-8) in which both € and £ are recorded using multiple bytes. That means that `"€"` is a string of *three* bytes, not just one.

When you use `$text[0]` you're getting only *the first byte* of the first character, and so it doesn't match the three bytes of `"€"`. You need to get the first three bytes instead, to check whether one string starts with another.

Here’s the function I use to do that:

```
function string_starts_with($string, $prefix) {
    return substr($string, 0, strlen($prefix)) == $prefix;
}
```

The question mark appears because the first byte of `"€"` isn’t enough to encode a whole character: the error is indicated by ‘�’ when available, otherwise ‘?’.